# Получить базовый класс из производного c#

Tags: c#

Есть базовый и производные классы. Есть функция в которую подается базовый класс.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CustomClass test = new CustomClass() { Id = 10, Comment = "Test Class", Value = "2000102" };
        ShowData(test); // В консоль выводится "CustomClass"
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

        private static void ShowData(BaseClass baseClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(baseClass.ToString());                
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomClass: BaseClass
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

**Вопрос**:

Можно ли имеющийся CustomClass преобразовать в BaseClass?
Аналог следующего кода:

```
public BaseClass ToBaseClass()
{
  return new BaseClass() {Id = this.Id, Comment = this.Comment};
}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? CustomClass уже и так является BaseClass.

Comment: Можно, получайте! `BaseClass customClass = new CustomClass() { Id = 10, Value="test", Comment ="Test Value"};`

Comment: @АндрейNOP немного изменил вопрос

Comment: @PavelMayorov все равно показывает как CustomClass

Comment: Не понятно чего вы добиваетесь. Вы можете переопределить метод ToString в базовом классе чтобы он выводил то что вам нужно, а не использовал стандартную реализацию из класса Object

Comment: @АндрейNOP Есть класс описывающий таблицу в БД в EF. Для View, я сделал производный класс и добавил несколько свойств. Но при записи в БД, мне нужен заполненный базовый класс, без добавленных  в производный класс свойств/полей.

Comment: Ну т.е. вам нужна операция клонирования, вам придется писать ее явно как в вопросе `ToBaseClass`, либо действовать через рефлексию, либо искать какие-то готовые решения. Если таких мест не много, то первый вариант, как мне кажется, самый лучший.

Comment: @MaximK ну ЁКЛМН! Если у вас вопрос по EF - так и задавайте его про EF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), при запуске приложения создайте нужный маппинг:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config => config.CreateMap<CustomClass, BaseClass>());
```

Потом, просто используйте его:

```
BaseClass baseClass = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<BaseClass>(test);

ShowData(baseClass); // BaseClass
```

Comment: Только что наткнулся на него...

Comment: @MaximK, последняя версия автомаппера не имеет статического метода `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap();`, поэтому я про него не стал писать.