# Преобразовать базовый экземпляр класса в его наследника

Tags: c#

Есть базовый класс:

```
public class VirtualObj : ICloneable
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public List<СharacteristicVirtualObj> Сharacteristics { get; set; } = new List<СharacteristicVirtualObj>();

    public VirtualObj(int Id)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var clone = this.MemberwiseClone();
        (clone as VirtualObj).Сharacteristics = this.Сharacteristics.GetRange(0, this.Сharacteristics.Count);
        return clone;
    }

}
```

Есть класс - наследник:

```
public class PredictionVirtualObj : VirtualObj
{
    public Predict Predict { get; set; }
}
```

Я копирую экземпляр базового класса и хочу из него сделать его наследника. Компилятор ругается, что просто привести тип нельзя:

```
PredictionVirtualObj obj = (PredictionVirtualObj)objOld.Clone(); // Копируем объект VirtualObj и преобразуем его в PredictionVirtualObj (!)
obj.Predict = this; // заполняем новое свойство, но до сюда компилятор не доходит
```

Соответственно, вопрос: как мне скопированный экземпляр `VirtualObj` вставить в наследника `PredictionVirtualObj`?

Comment: Никак. Придется писать код формирования `PredictionVirtualObj` из `VirtualObj` явно. Обходной путь — [использовать маппер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/831094/218063)

Comment: @АндрейNOP т.е. делать как clone, создавать новый экземпляр наследника и в него ручками все перекидывать из базового класса?

Comment: Либо рассмотреть вариант агрегации вместо наследования, возможно она подойдет вам больше

Comment: @АндрейNOP В этом случае я полиморфизмом не смогу пользоваться. Что же, буду делать руками. Проблема не в лени, а в том, что теперь когда я добавлю новое поле в `VirtualObj` нужно будет еще и не забывать дописывать его не только в метод Copy, но и в наследнике в методе трансформации базового объекта в наследник. Кроме этого теперь проблема такая: если метод трансформации будет в наследнике, то я не буду иметь доступ к {get;} свойству базового класса, например Id. Ну и проблемы же с этим даункастом

Comment: Это не даункаст. Это смена типа и в .NET она невозможна. При даункасте фактический тип объекта не меняется.

Comment: @АндрейNOP "downcasting - преобразования от базового типа к производному". Инфа от метанита, в моем случае все так и есть,  `VirtualObj ` - базовый должен быть преобразован в наследника -`PredictionVirtualObj`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81814/discussion-between-aleksandr-sergeevich-and--nop).

Comment: Ну это выражение некорректно. Повторюсь: фактически тип объекта в .NET изменить нельзя. Мы может изменить тип ссылки *только если там объект фактически нужного нам типа*. Если у вас `class B : A { }`, то вы не можете написать `A a = new A(); B b = (B)a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете сделать собственную реализацию MemberwiseClone, которую не придется обновлять после добавления или удаления свойств. Используйте метод [Type.GetProperties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Type_GetProperties_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_) чтобы плучить список свойств класса, и последоватеьно копируйте значения свойств из одного класса в другой с помощью методов [PropertyInfo.GetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_System_Object___) и [PropertyInfo.SetValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads).

Кроме этого, вы можете использовать [атрибуты](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes) для более тонкой настройки вашего метода MemverwiseCone. Например, игнорировать некоторые свойства при клонировании. Метод [PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) позволяет узнать имее ли указанное свойство какой-нибудь атрибут.

Comment: Хорошо, вопрос собственно был не о клоне, но постараюсь прикрутить Ваш ответ в вопросу :)

Answer (score 1):

Я прошу прощения, может быть, я сейчас какую нибудь глупость скажу, а что, если делать вот так:

```
    VirtualObj vo;
    ...
    string tmp = JsonSerializer.Serialize<VirtualObj>(vo);
    PredictionVirtualObj pvo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<PredictionVirtualObj>(tmp);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как вариант)) Еще как вариант это использовать столь популярный нынче automapper, думаю он будет оптимизированнее и позволит более тонко настраивать конвертацию

Answer (score 0):

В итоге, на основании ответа @Uranus получилось вот такое решение:
В `PredictionVirtualObj` создается конструктор, который при создании экземпляра класса наследника автоматически перекидывает значение полей из базового класса( `VirtualObj`). Но это не работает с readonly полями, они заполняются через обращение к конструктору базового класса (base, в моем примере поле Id).

```
using DeepCopy;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
public class PredictionVirtualObj : VirtualObj
{
    public Predict Predict { get; } // новое свойство, которого нет в базовом классе

    public PredictionVirtualObj(VirtualObj virtualObj, Predict Predict, int Id) : base(Id = virtualObj.Id)
    {
        virtualObj = DeepCopier.Copy(virtualObj); // глубоко копируем базовый объект, чтобы этот объект наследник не влиял на свойства базового объекта
        this.Predict = Predict;

        // Рефлексия, перезаполняем свойства автоматически
        // Первый базовый класс, откуда переносим
        Type typeVirtualObj = typeof(VirtualObj);
        PropertyInfo[] propInfosVirtualObj = typeVirtualObj.GetProperties();
        // Второй класс наследник - куда переносим
        Type typePredictionVirtualObj = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propInfosPredictionVirtualObj = typePredictionVirtualObj.GetProperties();

        //Фукнция, находит необходимое поле по имени
        PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfoForName(PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos, string Name)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo i in propertyInfos)
            {
                if(i.Name == Name) return i;
            }

            return null;
        }

        PropertyInfo propertyFound = null;
         // Перебираем все поля в базовом классе
        foreach (PropertyInfo i in propInfosVirtualObj)
        {
            propertyFound = GetPropertyInfoForName(propInfosPredictionVirtualObj, i.Name); // ищем такое же поле в классе наследнике
            if(propertyFound != null && propertyFound.CanWrite == true) // если такое поле найдено и оно не const и не readonly
                propertyFound.SetValue(this, i.GetValue(virtualObj)); // перекидываем значение из базового объекта в создаваемого конструктором наследника

            // Обнуляем переменную
            propertyFound = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Единственный ньюанс, то что это не глубокое копирование получается, сейчас подумаю как организовать глубокое копирование

Comment: В общем, я только что глянул, как оказалось, у меня и так по условию задачи в аргументы приходила глубокая копия базового объекта. Чтобы данный конструктор глубоко скопировал базовый экземпляр класса и дальше на него не влиял достаточно в самом начале конструктора написать: `virtualObj = DeepCopier.Copy(virtualObj);` и указать используемую библиотеку `using DeepCopy;` (ее можно добавить в проект через NuGet)

Comment: Добавил глубокое копирование